# PHP on Windows: LDAP (5.2) or Fileinfo (5.3), but not both?

Tags: php, windows, ldap, fileinfo

I have got PHP 5.2.14 running successfully on Windows, with the LDAP extension loading and working correctly.  I installed 5.2 because it appeared to be that php_ldap.dll wasn't available for 5.3.  Now it looks like the Fileinfo extension is *only* available for 5.3!

(I'm a linux chap mostly, and have generally been sheltered in the happy world of `apt-get`, so forgive me if I've missed something obvious.)

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to have both of these extensions running on Windows, and if so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by installing the Fileinfo.dll from PHP 5.2.5.  See [my blog post](http://samwilson.id.au/2010/10/26/fileinfo/) for more info.